# JSON Response from fetch omitting fields that are empty

Tags: node.js, object, fetch

My backend logs (A) show that the extra data fields show up in all my components, which can see sends the data in mybackend code (B). But the frontend logs (C) from the frontend code (D) doesnt print the extraData fields for the empty objects. Why is that? There is no other middleware function or code in between the data sent between the two and I've been scratching my head along with GPT for two days now.

A) Backend logs

```
{
      name: 'NFT Trending table',
      componentName: 'nft-trending-table',
      extraData: {},
      componentIndexes: [Array]
    },
    {
      name: 'Morning Update',
      componentName: 'morning-update',
      extraData: {},
      componentIndexes: [Array]
    },
```

B) Backend code

```
console.log("HEY, account", updatedAccount.dashboardSchemas.memecoins)
        return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: `Account found for ${walletAddress}`, account: updatedAccount})
```

C) Frontend logs

```
{
      name: 'NFT Trending table',
      componentName: 'nft-trending-table',
      componentIndexes: [Array]
    },
    {
      name: 'Morning Update',
      componentName: 'morning-update',
      componentIndexes: [Array]
    },
```

D) Frontend code

```
let response = await fetch(LOCAL8080 + "/account/getAccount?walletAddress=" + walletAddress, getOptions)
let results = await response.json()
console.log("results", results.account.dashboardSchemas.memecoins)
```